# Объект роль не имеет атрибута "is_bot_managed"

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Мне нужно проверять, является ли роль ролью интеграции или ролью бота. В документации есть:

```py
discord.Role.is_bot_managed() и
discord.Role.is_integration()
```

Если их просто вызывать, то все работает нормально:

```py
role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, id = айди)
await ctx.send(role.is_bot_managed())
>>> True
```

Но если попытаться сделать что-то похожее на:

```py
role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, id = айди)
if role.is_bot_managed():
    await ctx.send("Это роль бота")
```

Я получаю ошибку

```py
Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Role' object has no attribute 'is_bot_managed'
```

Что я могу с этим сделать или могу ли я как-то по-другому проверять роль?

Comment: У меня всё работает, какая у вас версия `discord.py`? В доках написано, что это с версии 1.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего, у тебя стоит старая версия discord.py, потому что в документации написано, что функцию **is_bot_managed()** добавлена только в версии **1.6** и выше.
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.htmlhighlight=is_bot_managed#discord.Role.is_bot_managed

Просто обнови discord.py и всё должно заработать, удачи!